# verify textbox value from c# in asp.net (if matched value = textbox.text else value = "no match found")

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web application using ASP.net. In the application I am calling active directory to check alias of the employee using the code written below:

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "LDAP://" + "OU=UserAccounts,DC=abc,DC=corp,DC=nextel,DC=com";
        string filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";
        string[] propertiesToLoad = new string[1] {"samaccountname"};

        using (DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(path))
        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = 
             new DirectorySearcher(root, filter, propertiesToLoad))
        using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                string name = (string)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
                 if (name == TextBoxSearch.Text)
                {
                    TextBoxSearch.Text = name;
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBoxSearch.Text = "No match found";
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I am in a need of a functionality where I can input an alias into a textbox and while clicking search button, it would be check against the result of the code above. if match found then the same box show that field and if not found then "no match found". How can it be implemented? The above code only gives no match found.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**
you are iterating all the items in results and overwriting the text box text. 
you can only see the matching text for final item of the results.

**solution:** 
you need to break the loop when you found matching item

```
    bool matchfound= false;
    using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
    {
        foreach (SearchResult result in results)
        {
            string name = (string)result.Properties["samaccountname"][0];
            if (name == TextBoxSearch.Text)
            {
                TextBoxSearch.Text = name;
                matchfound =true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!matchfound)
        TextBoxSearch.Text = "No match found";
```

Comment: this code always give No match found since we are explicitly setting value of the textbox to No match found and then that value we are comparing with name which will never match.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the value in `TextBoxSearch.Text` to filter the search and then just setting the value back to `TextBoxSearch.Text` if it's found, you can shorten this a bit using LINQ's [`Any()`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b):

If all you want to do is display a message in `TextBoxSearch` if the name isn't found, try this:

```
using (var results = searcher.FindAll().Cast<SearchResult>())
{
    if (!results.Any(result => Convert.ToString(result.Properties["samaccountname"][0]) == TextBoxSearch.Text))
    {
        TextBoxSearch.Text = "No match found";
    }
}
```

Comment: in spite of having using System.Linq; at the top of the code, it says missing using directives.

Comment: it says "'System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection' does not contain a definition for 'any' and no extension method 'any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" I am using .NET 4.5

Comment: it gives no match found all the time even if input a value which exists in there.